# How to specify Kafka custom configuration of streaming queries with Kafka data source (e.g. Confluent Cloud authentication)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-platform

I want to read and write using structured streaming against Confluent Cloud. The problem is that I can't find the method to authenticate in the documentation.

I have the next data connection:

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=https
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
request.timeout.ms=20000
bootstrap.servers=pkc-nq5ga.westeurope.azure.confluent.cloud:9092
retry.backoff.ms=500
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="<CLUSTER_API_KEY>" password="<CLUSTER_API_SECRET>";
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```

When I've tested against localhost without a password and I haven't had any problems with it.

```
val inputStream = spark.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
    .option("subscribe", inputTopic)
    .option("startingOffsets", startingOffsetsValue)
    .load()

 outputStream.writeStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", outputBrokers)
    .option("topic", outputTopic)
    .option("checkpointLocation", pathCheckpoint)
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

Someone knows how to pass the authentication configuration to get to the confluent cloud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the official documentation [Kafka Specific Configurations](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations):

> Kafka’s own configurations can be set via DataStreamReader.option with `kafka.` prefix, e.g, `stream.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")`

With that, we can pass the connection data, e.g.

```
.option("kafka.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https")
```